# Decidability of prime gap sequences

Tags: prime-numbers, computability-theory

Is the following problem undecidable?

> Given a sequence of $n$ gaps $d_1,d_2,...,d_n$, does there exist a sequence of $n+1$ primes $p_1,p_2,...,p_{n+1}$ such that $p_{i+1} - p_i = d_i$ ?

If not, is the problem still undecidable if we pick a fixed $n$, e.g. only one gap (n=1), or only two gaps (n=2).

With *undecidable* I mean that you cannot build a Turing machine that given the sequence $d_1,...,d_n$ as input *always* halts and gives the correct answer.

Comment: Suppose that there are no primes $p_{1},p_{2}$ with $p_{2}-p_{1} = d_{1}.$ How would your Turing machine know this?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: that is the question, is there a formal proof that it is undecidable?

Comment: I am not sure. I do not see a way to prove that a particular  prime gap is impossible, nor can I imagine one, but that does not mean it is impossible to construct one!

Comment: Are the primes consecutive or not? (The wording suggests nonconsecutive.)

Comment: The prime k-tuples conjecture implies that the question is decidable.  Current technology can only decide if a gap sequence is admissible, and can only say yes it is realized in finite time.

Comment: Also current technology can only say that a number d divides the size of a gap (Dirichlet). And, roughly, how large that multiple must be. (Linnik, Xylouris)

Comment: Harvey Friedman has suggested that the 1-gap case may be an example of a c.e. problem that is not decidable and also not equivalent to the halting problem. If this were true, it would be an instance of the long-sought natural examples of intermediate Turing degrees between $0$ and $0'$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: did he write it in a paper? (have you got the reference?). If yes you can also convert the comment to an answer.

Comment: I heard him say this in a conference talk, in response to a question.

Comment: @Joel, are there any reasons to believe that this question undecidable? It is a question on which we are making regular progresses, and with a little optimism, we can hope it will decided relatively soon...

Comment: I have no reason to believe it either way, and it might have been mere speculation on Harvey's part---he had simply suggested it as something that, for all we know currently, might be the case.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, is it known that this 1-gap problem is not equivalent to the halting problem?  Or is that  also just a conjecture (or speculation) of Harvey's?

Comment: That was what I took to be Harvey's speculation, namely, both sides of it: that is is not decidable and that it is not equivalent to $0'$. I don't think he was asserting it as a conjecture, but rather perhaps as a kind of challenge example of what might be true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably unknown. The problem is that we know very little about the distribution of prime numbers. In general, decidability questions only become interesting when we "have a good grasp" about the object we are manipulating. It is easy to generate decidability questions which are only hard because of our limited knowledge. Here are a few examples:

- Given two rationals $a<b$, can one decide whether there a zero of Reimann's zeta function whose real part belongs to $(a,b)$?
- Given a finite sequence of digits $w$, can one decide whether $w$ appears in the decimal expansion of $\pi$?
- Given an integer $n$, can one decide whether the Collatz sequence starting at $n$ eventually reaches $1$?

In all three cases, the answer is assumed to be positive for a trivial reason (in the first case, by simply checking whether $a<1/2<b$ or whether $a<-2n<b$ for some nonnegative integer $n$, in the second and third case by answering `yes' all the time) but proving this does not appear to be simpler than the general conjecture. I feel like your problem somewhat falls into this category.

Comment: Minor correction: $\zeta(s)$ also has some trivial zeros.